# TabItem ControlTemplate element Visibility

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, tabitem

I have defined a custom `ControlTemplate` for `TabItem` where I am having besides the `ContentPresenter` a `Button` (to hide the tab when clicked).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Border>
                          <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="x" Visibility="Visible"/>
                         </Grid>
                    </Border>      
                </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want the `Button` to be `Visible` only for certain `TabItems` and `Collapsed` for others. `Collapsed` state should be the default and I don't understand how to set it to `Visible` for certain tabs.

If the tab items are like

```
<TabItem Header="Normal tab">
    <Grid />
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Closable tab">
    <Grid/>
</TabItem>
```

and I want to have the "Closable tab" to be showing this `Button` but the "Normal tab" not showing this `Button`, how can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TabItem`'s `Tag` property to identify its type, and watch this type from inside `Button` with `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green" Margin="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="x">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=Tag}" Value="Closable">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem Header="Normal tab">
        <Grid />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Tag="Closable" Header="Closable tab">
        <Grid />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I edited `Border` attributes a little bit just to visual separate tabs, they are not necessary for this example to work.